# How to use Twitter Bootstrap components and plugins individually?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to use *pieces* of Twitter Bootstrap (say, *just* the tooltips and the vertical tabs) in an application that is not built using Twitter Bootstrap but does use jQuery? Or do you have to include / use the entire framework?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can customize Bootstrap for using only what you need.

So you can make your own Bootstrap build by selecting the components and jQuery plugins you want.

Then you get a part of Bootstrap instead of the full repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Boostrap JavaScript Plugins (tooltips, modal etc) individually by referring their individual `*.js` file. But, beware that some plugins and CSS components depend on other plugins. If you include plugins individually, make sure to check for these dependencies in the docs.

For this you've to download the full source folder of the boostrap either using npm or from bootrap website.