# How to display pop up text on mouse hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

I want to load some content from a DIV tag as pop up text when i hover over an image. When i mouse leave from that image pop should disappear and when i again mouse over image content should show as pop up text. I am using HTML, Jquery, JS for this. It will be very useful if i get a solution using jquery load() method. Let me know ur response.

Comment: Look into using the jQuery UI dialog method. You have to attempt a solution, then we can help you debug it/figure out issues you are having trouble with.

Comment: what you tried? else Google it, you'll get loads of jQuery tooltips

Comment: Any reason for the jquery load() method? Can't you set the CSS for the div on hidden and then display it onmouseover from the image?

Comment: @Matthias I want use load() because i want page performance to be high. only needful content shud get loaded

Answer (score 22):

Or, without javascript:

```
<div class="tooltip-wrap">
  <img src="/some/image/file.jpg" alt="Some Image" />
  <div class="tooltip-content">
    Here is some content for the tooltip
  </div> 
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```css
.tooltip-wrap {
  position: relative;
}
.tooltip-wrap .tooltip-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: .5em;
  min-width: 10rem;
}
.tooltip-wrap:hover .tooltip-content {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: If you have 100 images in the page, your code increases of 500 lines.

Comment: If you have 100 images in the page, you have bigger problems than 500 lines of HTML... just sayin.  Assuming you were lazi loading images below the fold, a javascript solution would be very prone to memory leaks if not implemented properly.

Answer (score 13):

You could also try something very simple like:

```
<acronym title="pop-up text"><img src=...></acronym>
```

Comment: or <abbr>, but same thing.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap) with [the tooltip plugin](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips).

If you want just the plugin, [you can build your own Bootstrap with the plugin only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11640442/652669).

Finally if you want to stylize your tooltip, use [CSStooltip.com](http://csstooltip.com/).

Example :

[image]

```
span.tooltip:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-width: 10px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: transparent #FFFFFF transparent transparent;
      top: 11px;
      left: -24px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add the `title` attribute to the image. You don't need any extra tags or styling, just an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
<p id="icon">Text to hover over</p>
<p id="info" style="display: none">Text to popup</p>
```

Then, finish it with javascript.

```
<script>
var e = document.getElementById('icon');
e.onmouseover = function() {
  document.getElementById('info').style.display = 'block';
}
e.onmouseout = function() {
  document.getElementById('info').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

If you hover over the text, another will popup.