# How to pop up an image on hover?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My page having a table which contain more columns and rows. Each of the rows and columns having small images. the for loop is using for calling the images. I want to pop up the images on hover.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please describe your requirement in more specific way? How that pop up image will disappear?

Comment: Without javascript :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683620/how-to-display-pop-up-text-on-mouse-hover

Hope it will help you.

Comment: please try bootstrap.. maybe you can find your answer there

Answer (score 1):

I could imagine something like this here:

```
$(".image").hover(function(){
    //display bigger image here
}, function() {
    //hide it here
});
```

Alternative, you can use CSS `:hover`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

With JQuery mouseover event : http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

And a popup plugin like magnific popup : http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

Answer (score 0):

Code below can create a pop up:

```
$("body").on('mouseover','#image_id',function(){      
//popup image.    
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple You can use jquery hover function like this

```
$('img').hover(function(){

    $(this).css('width' , '500px');
    $(this).css('height' , '500px');
},function(){

    $(this).css('width' , '200px');
    $(this).css('height' , '200px');
})
```

and this is html code of images

```
<div id="main_container">
    <div id="div1">
        <img src="img/angelinasmall.jpg" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" />
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
        <img src="img/hayden.jpg" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" />
    </div>
    <div id="div3">
        <img src="img/milla.jpg" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"/>
    </div>
</div>
```